# GCP BigQuery source data from Google Sheet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, g-suite

I am trying to get the source data of a BigQuery table from **Google Sheet**.

I specified the source data location to be "Google Drive" and put in the correct URL to a Google Sheet.

However, I encountered "Invalide source" error when creating the table. I am sure the URL is valid.

*Failed to create table: Invalid source URI: https://docs.google.com/a/sph.com.sg/spreadsheets/d/1e2ognNM1aFd4t_hictq4rgL4aj1ormObgEun7pHxa8w/edit?usp=sharing*

I am not sure what went wrong. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I discovered that I did not select the file format as "Google Sheets" previously. Upon doing so, I got a different error message as follows: "Failed to create table: Google Sheets format is only allowed for Google Drive URIs" Hope somebody can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to your source URI format. When you create a new table from Google Drive, you have to use the file’s URI that takes the form: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=[file_id]

To access a Google Drive file's URI in this format:

1. Go to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) .
2. Right-click on the file and select Get shareable link.